# How to make a SwiftUI view Scrollable?

Tags: ios, swiftui

How do I make my Body View as Scrollable?

I need to make the large Lorem ipsum text scrollable.

```swift
struct FeatureDetail : View {
    var body: some View {  
       //Scrollable {  Does Not work
        VStack{
            Image("wwdc")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .padding()

            Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.").lineLimit(nil).padding(20)

            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("WWDC"), displayMode:.automatic)
       //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Use List Instead if using ScrollView.

Comment: `ScrollView` works for me, at least in watchOS

Answer (score 14):

You can use `List` instead of `ScrollView` to enable scrolling. Wrap your content in a `List`:

```
List {
  VStack{
    Image("wwdc")
      .resizable()
      .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
      .padding()

    Text("Very long text").lineLimit(nil).padding(20)

  }.navigationBarTitle(Text("WWDC"), displayMode:.automatic)
}
```

Comment: Currently ScrollView seems to have problems with Text as it makes a horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Is using List a great workaround or actually the correct solution for the future?

Comment: @funkenstrahlen it’s only a workaround. We have to wait for the next release to see if this has been fixed.